# Having BeautifulSoup skip a section of my html..or split it

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html class="client-nojs" dir="ltr" lang="en">
<body>
<h2><span class="mw-headline" id="Danish">Danish</span></h2>
<h3><span class="mw-headline" id="Noun">Noun</span><span class="mw-editsection">
</h3>
<p><strong class="Latn headword" lang="da">bringen</strong>blabla</span></p>
<ol>
<li><span class="form-of-definition">blabla</span></li>
</ol>
<hr/>
<h2><span class="mw-headline" id="German">German</span>blabla</span></h2>
<h3><span class="mw-headline" id="Noun">Noun</span><span class="mw-editsection">
    </h3>
<h3><span class="mw-headline" id="Etymology">blabla</span></h3>
<p>From <span class="etyl"></p>
<h3><span class="mw-headline" id="Pronunciation">Pronunciation</span></h3>
<ul>
</body>
</html>
```

I need BS to ignore everything until `<h2><span class="mw-headline" id="German">`. Preferably I would have it split when I create my soup variable. The `id="German"` part is not variable, everything else is.

I tried using the built-in split-function, but that didn't work. Also looked at some of the answers here but I didn't get any wiser from them. Tips?

EDIT: As you can see, there are two spans with the 'noun' id. I only need the one that comes right after 'German'. I'm not sure how I would BeautifulSoup only find the second one, if not by splitting.

Comment: What do you mean with "I need BS to look over everything ..."? You can iterate through the DOM, and just stop the iteration at any point, if you have "seen" enough. You might want to show what you have tried, what the output is, and what output you wish to see.

Comment: Usually when people ask how to alter/delete things from the tree, they're really just asking how to perform a search to find the things they want.  Instead of asking about how to accomplish your goal, you've asked about your [attempted solution](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't entirely clear in my question. I need it to ignore everything until a certain point, and only then start iterating.

Answer (score 2):

You probably can find what you want with the [`Element.find_all_next()` method](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all-next-and-find-next), which lets you search the whole tree **after** a given element:

```
start = soup.select('h2 span#German')[0]
headlines = start.find_all_next('span', id='Noun')
```

This'll find all spans with an `id` attribute set to `Noun` listed *after* the German `<h2>` tag.

There is a corresponding `Element.find_next()` method to find just the first next match instead of all.

In other words, `find_all_next()` and `find_next()` work *exactly* like `find_all()` and `find()` but only search the tree past a given starting point. There are also [`find_all_previous()` and `find_previous()` methods](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all-previous-and-find-previous) to search in the other direction.

Demo:

```
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup('''\
... <!DOCTYPE html>
... 
... <html class="client-nojs" dir="ltr" lang="en">
... <body>
... <h2><span class="mw-headline" id="Danish">Danish</span></h2>
... <h3><span class="mw-headline" id="Noun">Noun</span><span class="mw-editsection">
... </h3>
... <p><strong class="Latn headword" lang="da">bringen</strong>blabla</span></p>
... <ol>
... <li><span class="form-of-definition">blabla</span></li>
... </ol>
... <hr/>
... <h2><span class="mw-headline" id="German">German</span>blabla</span></h2>
... <h3><span class="mw-headline" id="Noun">Noun</span><span class="mw-editsection">
...     </h3>
... <h3><span class="mw-headline" id="Etymology">blabla</span></h3>
... <p>From <span class="etyl"></p>
... <h3><span class="mw-headline" id="Pronunciation">Pronunciation</span></h3>
... <ul>
... </body>
... </html>
... ''')
>>> start = soup.select('h2 span#German')[0]
>>> start.find_all_next('span', id='Noun')
[<span class="mw-headline" id="Noun">Noun</span>]
```